# Problems with pointers in asembly function transposing matrix

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86-64, transpose

In my code im trying to transpose dynamic matrix (IN64) using function written in assembly
It seems that im trying to read from outside of matrix or i`m making a mistake while trying to point from where should my function move and save bytes.

Please help me with this problem as it is important for me to understand properly what mistake i`m making

Here`s c++ code using function transpose

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" void transpose(INT64**, INT64);

// Function for displaying the matrix
void printMatrix(INT64** matrix, INT64 n) {
    for (INT64 i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (INT64 j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    INT64 n = 8; // Matrix size

    // Initialization of matrix A
    INT64** A = new INT64 * [n];
    for (INT64 i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        A[i] = new INT64[n];
        for (INT64 j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            A[i][j] = i * n + j; // Filling matrix A
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Matrix before transposition:" << std::endl;
    printMatrix(A, n); // Display the matrix before transposition

    // Calling the transpose function
    transpose(A, n);

    std::cout << "Matrix after transposition:" << std::endl;
    printMatrix(A, n); // Display the matrix after transposition

    // Deallocate memory
    for (INT64 i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        delete[] A[i];
    }
    delete[] A;

    return 0;
}
```

and heres transpose function

```
.code


transpose PROC
    mov r10, rax ; Store the dimension 8 in r10
    mov r11, rax ; Store the dimension 8 in r11

loopRow:
    mov r8, [rcx + rax]      ; Initialize the row index (i) to 8 (8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
    mov r9, [rcx + 8 * rax]      ; Initialize the column index (j) to 8 (56,48,40,32,24,16,8,0)

loopColumn:
    mov rdx, [r9 + rdi * 8] ; Load the element from the matrix (56,48,40,32,24,16,8,0)
    mov rsi, [rcx + rdi * 8] ; Load the element from the matrix (7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)
    mov [r9 + rdi * 8], rsi ; Assign the element to the transposed location
    mov [rcx + rdi * 8], rdx
    inc rdi        ; Move to the next column
    cmp rdi, r10   ; Check if all columns are finished
    jl loopColumn
    inc r11        ; Move to the next row
    cmp rdi, r11   ; Check if all rows are finished
    jl loopRow

    ret
transpose ENDP

END
```

Im feel defeated trying to fix that code in many ways but it seems i`m simply missing something important while my function is not working

[**edit**]

This is my next code that tries to solve it:

```
.code

transpose PROC
    mov r10, rdx ; matrix size n
    mov r11, rdx ; matrix size n

loopRow:
    mov r10, r11
    mov r12, [rcx + 8 * r10 - 8] ; el.(64) of the matrix
    mov r13, [rcx + 8 * r11 - 8] ; el.(64) of the matrix

loopColumn:
    mov rdx, [rcx + 8 * r10 - 8]
    mov rsi, [rcx + 8 * r11 - 8]
    mov r8, rdx
    mov [rcx + 8 * r10 - 8], rsi
    mov [rcx + 8 * r11 - 8], rdx

    dec r10        ; Move to the next column
    jnz loopColumn
    dec r11        ; Move to the next row
    jnz loopRow

    ret
transpose ENDP
END
```

Comment: Ok, so have you tried debugging this?  Starting at the beginning, what's in `rax` (vs,. what's supposed to be in it) at the start of the procedure??

Comment: At the beggining rax stores dimension n, while rcx stores address to matrix

Comment: And you've verified this by examination in the debugger?

Comment: Yes i verified it in debugger using breakpoints

Comment: I don't know any calling convention that passes a parameter in `rax`.  What system are you running on?  Maybe `rax` happens to have a value that looks logical, but is just some value computed by `main` before the function call.  Or, maybe I just don't know this ABI.  Anyway, it might be helpful for you to add to your print matrix, to show the the addresses in addition to the values, especially as it seems you're using jagged arrays for the matrix.

Comment: Ok, i saw my 1st problems which you pointed at, `rax` was some random value and i received dimension of matrix in register `rdx`
I swapped every mention of `rax` to `rdx` and every `rdx` to `rax`
Code still is not running with problems being in line 13 and 14,15,16
`mov rdx, [r9 + rdi * 8]`
`mov rsi, [rcx + rdi * 8]`
`mov [r9 + rdi * 8], rsi `
`mov [rcx + rdi * 8], rdx`

Comment: Ok, here's how to debug complex addressing modes.  Split into two instructions so you can see the effective address. First use `lea rax, [r9 + rdi * 8]`, then `mov rdx, [rax]`.  This will allow you to see the memory address actually being used, in `rax`.  Compare those addresses with your address&value printing in the c code, to see if you're accessing legit locations.

Comment: I have changed how assembly function works and i want to say that instead of making matrix transposed i get my matrix where row order is changed from 1..8 to 8..1
I dont know what i need to change to get it work with column so that `r13` could work

Comment: Please don't change the code in the question when an answer exists! You can **add** additional code like I just did through an edit that doesn't modify what was there already. Regarding the transpose: this new code is just as unsalvageable as the previous code. Read the comment below my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how the current code can be salvaged.

- You seem to be guessing about where the arguments are.
- You are using RDI as an index without initializing it beforehand. I suppose 0 would be appropriate, but even then it would still be wrong to use the same scaled index `rdi * 8` for both the column and the row. For the column you'd need a step of 8 (corresponding to `inc rdi`), but for the row you'd need a step of 64 (corresponding to `add rdi, 8`).
- You are setting up R8 and R9 register with some values from memory (elements from the matrix), and in case of R8 you don't even use it afterwards. And for R9, you use what is an element from the array as if it were an address.
- ...

Some time ago I posted [a Q/A on the codereview site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221312/transposing-a-square-matrix-n-x-n). You should read it because it shows graphically what the below code does.

```
; TransposeSquareMatrix(A, n)
    mov     rbx, rdi        ; Address A is in RDI
    mov     rcx, rsi        ; Dimension n is in RSI
    imul    r8, rsi, 8      ; Step between rows
    dec     rcx
    jz      .c              ; It's a (1 x 1) matrix
.a: push    rcx             ; (1)
    mov     rsi, rbx        ; Column address
    mov     rdi, rbx        ; Row address
.b: add     rsi, 8          ; To next element in this row
    add     rdi, r8         ; To next element in this column
    mov     rax, [rsi]      ; Swap 2 elements
    mov     rdx, [rdi]
    mov     [rdi], rax
    mov     [rsi], rdx
    dec     rcx
    jnz     .b
    lea     rbx, [rbx + r8 + 8] ; To next element on main diagonal
    pop     rcx             ; (1)
    dec     rcx
    jnz     .a              ; Continu until (1 x 1) matrix
.c: ret
```

Comment: Instead of guessing, why don't you give my solution a chance? If it's the choice of argument registers that bothers you, then just start the procedure with next two instructions: `; TransposeSquareMatrix(A, n)` `mov rdi, rcx` `mov rsi, rdx`

Comment: After giving your code a chance im getting error here `std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";`
while printing out 1st row of not transposed matrix 0 1 2 3 ... 7. That error says that: The following exception was reported at location 0x00007FF6E5F5252B (1) in Project9.exe: 0xC0000005 (2): Access violation while reading at location 0x00000000FDFDFDFD (3).
Even if i dont use two instructions moving rcx, rdx to rdi and rsi im still having error in `mov rax, [rsi]` same but with location 0x00007FF6958D1E1D (1), 0xC0000005 (2) and 0x0000000000000008 (3)

Comment: @szyjas "while printing out 1st row of **not transposed** matrix" So even before running the transpose assembly code? Doesn't that mean you got a problem in your C++ program? I am confident that my assembly code will transpose a matrix of quadwords in-place, but on the premise that the address is in RDI and the dimension is in RSI. I can't help with the C++ part, so I suggest that you post a new question containing the latest version of the whole program and make sure to emphasize on the link with C++ (tag it with [tag:c++].

Comment: Maybe i should be  more precise about what i meant. While running c++ i see matrix before transposing, then after that only 1st row of "transposed" matrix before seeing error about i have written above. 1st row of transposed matrix looks like that: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7. If you are suggesting that it may be a problem with c++ part then i will ask a new question.