# Problems while printing out transposed matrix

Tags: c++, assembly, transpose

My problem is that after printing out 1st row of matrix after transposing im receiving an error telling me that im trying to access not accessible location

First post with asm discussion if i didnt told something thats maybe needed
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77376880/problems-with-pointers-in-asembly-function-transposing-matrix/77385269?noredirect=1#comment136574422_77385269)
There is my function in C++ calling a transpose function written in asm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" void transpose(INT64**, INT64);

// Function for displaying the matrix
void printMatrix(INT64** matrix, INT64 n) {
    for (INT64 i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (INT64 j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    INT64 n = 8; // Matrix size

    // Initialization of matrix A
    INT64** A = new INT64 * [n];
    for (INT64 i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        A[i] = new INT64[n];
        for (INT64 j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            A[i][j] = i * n + j; // Filling matrix A
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Matrix before transposition:" << std::endl;
    printMatrix(A, n); // Display the matrix before transposition

    // Calling the transpose function
    transpose(A, n);

    std::cout << "Matrix after transposition:" << std::endl;
    printMatrix(A, n); // Display the matrix after transposition

    // Deallocate memory
    for (INT64 i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        delete[] A[i];
    }
    delete[] A;

    return 0;
}
```

And here is asm function used in last iteration of my code

```
; TransposeSquareMatrix(A, n)
    mov     rdi, rcx
    mov     rsi, rdx
    mov     rbx, rdi        ; Address A is in RDI
    mov     rcx, rsi        ; Dimension n is in RSI
    imul    r8, rsi, 8      ; Step between rows
    dec     rcx
    jz      .c              ; It's a (1 x 1) matrix
.a: push    rcx             ; (1)
    mov     rsi, rbx        ; Column address
    mov     rdi, rbx        ; Row address
.b: add     rsi, 8          ; To next element in this row
    add     rdi, r8         ; To next element in this column
    mov     rax, [rsi]      ; Swap 2 elements
    mov     rdx, [rdi]
    mov     [rdi], rax
    mov     [rsi], rdx
    dec     rcx
    jnz     .b
    lea     rbx, [rbx + r8 + 8] ; To next element on main diagonal
    pop     rcx             ; (1)
    dec     rcx
    jnz     .a              ; Continu until (1 x 1) matrix
.c: ret
```

What maybe a problem? Is it c++ code or something else?

Comment: You are not preserving the registers required by the calling convention (`rbx`, `rsi` and `rdi`). Maybe pick other registers that don't need to be preserved.

Comment: `INT64**` isn't a contiguous 2D array like `int64_t arr[n][m]`, it's an array of pointers to arrays.  See [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/936687).  With your extra level of indirection, accessing an element requires 2 loads; that's why it's inefficient to do it that way.  Your asm is I think treating it like a proper 2D array.

Comment: Also [How-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c).  Even if you weren't using assembler this: `// Initialization of matrix A` is an absolutely awful way of creating a matrix with a uniform number of rows and columns.  What if there are 10000 rows?  Memory fragmentation through the roof, possible `new[]` failing in the creation loop somewhere in the middle, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I wouldn't recommend that.  Contiguous allocation but still an array of pointers still has an extra level of indirection to access it, preventing some compiler optimizations.  e.g. code-gen can't assume that `A[x][y]` is a different element from `A[z][y]`, since it can't assume 2 entries of the pointer array are different.  vs. with actual 2D arrays a single overlap check outside a loop is possible for two matrices, to fall back to a non-vectorize loop for example.  Or write a class that overloads `[]` for 2D indexing into one flat `int[]` or `std::vector<int>`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Actually some of the answers on that Q&A you linked are better than the accepted one, avoiding an extra array of row pointers.  e.g. one with `boost::multi_array<int64_t, 2>` for a 2D array of int64_t, which presumably does the 2D indexing manually into one contiguous allocation.  And another simple answer suggesting `std::vector` with manual `[i*n + j]` indexing, which is actually what I'd recommend especially for ease of interaction with asm.  (Or `int64_t *ptr = new`, but `vector.data()` can work, too.)  I wouldn't recommend row pointers except to efficiently swap rows.

Comment: I recommend passing a single pointer to the contiguous memory.  To access a matrix slot, use the formula `INT64 value = arr[(row * column_size) + column];`  This may be faster than passing a 2d matrix.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: A 2D array *is* contiguous.  That's just different syntax for the same asm-level object you'd get from `int64_t arr[rows][columns]`.  Some people incorrectly describe an array of pointers to arrays as a 2D array but it's not a multidimensional array in C or C++ terms. (The `arr[][]` syntax to access an element means something somewhat different when `arr` is an `int**` vs. when it's an `int (*)[]`.)  "2D matrix" doesn't have a specific technical meaning in C or C++, but it definitely doesn't mean this bad data structure the OP is using.  TL:DR: don't encourage bad terminology.

Comment: (Not that I recommend actually declaring a 2D VLA as a local array using stack space, but the syntax for declaring a pointer-to-1D-array which acts as a 2D array is more complex.  Anyway yes, manual indexing into a simple 1D array is a good way to go, especially when you want to interface with asm so you want it to be easy to be sure you're indexing the same way in both.)